# mapstruct uses the wrong overload setter

Tags: java, mapstruct

I am using mapstruct 1.5.2. I try to map a SaveAccountDTO object into a AccountUpdateParams.Company object from the Stripe Java library. It uses the builder pattern.

The generated method uses the wrong overloaded method : the builder have a setter with String type and a second setter with the same name and a EmptyParam enum type :

```
public Builder setName(String name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}

public Builder setName(EmptyParam name) {
    this.name = name;
    return this;
}
```

Mapstruct generates the following implementation :

```
AccountUpdateParams.Company.Builder company = com.stripe.param.AccountUpdateParams.Company.builder();

if ( value.getLegalName() != null ) {
    company.setName( Enum.valueOf( EmptyParam.class, value.getLegalName() ) );
}
```

But it is wrong as I would like to use the setName(String) setter :

```
company.setName( value.getLegalName() );
```

My mapping for this field is quite simple :

```
@Mapping(target = "name", source = "legalName")
```

Why does mapstruct choose to convert the input String into the enum to match the second setter? **Is there any way to go for the String setter?** I found no way to disable the implicit type conversion from the doc.

Answer (score 2):

I don't know if this is the best solution, but since you ask for **any** way to solve the issue, you can ignore the property, and map it with a method annotated with @AfterMapping:

```
@Mapping(target = "name", ignore = true)
AccountUpdateParams.Company toCompany(SaveAccountDTO saveAccountDTO)

@AfterMapping
default void setNameFromLegalName(SaveAccountDTO saveAccountDTO, @MappingTarget AccountUpdateParams.Company company) {        
    company.setName( saveAccountDTO.getLegalName() );                  
}
```

Comment: This is my current workaround, but I was hopping there would be a more elegant solution. Every time I have a string property I need to map the fields manually, and there's a lot of them.

Comment: I know that if you define multiple constructors, you can add the @Default on which one you want that MapStruct has to use, I don't know if can also work for setters. Maybe you can try. 
(Documentation for declaring default constructor: https://mapstruct.org/documentation/stable/reference/html/#mapping-with-constructors)

Comment: I cannot modify the target setters as these classes come from the Stripe Java library

Comment: This actually a limitation of MapStruct. It doesn't allow using overloaded setters. If you would like to see such a functionality then please create an issue

Comment: @Filip, if the signatures of the desired setter overloads are somewhat predictable, it should be possible to solve this with a custom `AccessorNamingStrategy`, right?

Comment: This has already been filed, right? https://github.com/mapstruct/mapstruct/issues/1135